# PTIJ: Why Is Odin Considered Sonless?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

When Zelophead's daughter's demand inheritance on their father's behalf, they state:

> ...לָמָּה יִגָּרַע שֵׁם-אָבִינוּ מִתּוֹךְ מִשְׁפַּחְתּוֹ, כִּי אֵין לוֹ בֵּן.
>
> Why is our father's name *Yggr* amongst his family, for he has no son...

Yggr is one of [Odin's many names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_names_of_Odin), and Odin had at least 2 sons, Thor and Baldr, and as many as 4 if you accept the גירסא that includes Víðarr and Váli.

Given that, why is Yggr used as an epithet for someone with no sons in Jewish Tradition when he did in fact have sons?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Perhaps Yggr was Odin's name before he had sons...

Answer (score 3):

*Lichorah* this is not a *kashye* at all, since the sons were gods and gods may not inherit in Eretz Yisrael, as the *passuk* says

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%97_%D7%99%D7%97

> לְמַעַן תֵּדַע כִּי אֲנִי יְהוָה בְּקֶרֶב הָאָרֶץ
>
> In order that you should know that only I Hashem am in the midst of
> the land

Answer (score 2):

[The name "Yggr" means "terrible"](https://norse-mythology.org/cosmology/yggdrasil-and-the-well-of-urd). Sure, "Tzlophchad the Terrible" might sound like a cool nickname on the face of things ([on the battlefield, for example](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Baal_Haturim_on_Numbers.14.44.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=en)), but it's a bad legacy to have, especially in the field of your children's shidduchim. The daughters of Tzlophchad demanded to know why their father must be remembered as a terrible father, simply due to the fact that he didn't have sons and thereby, made their tribe lose out on a portion of land, thus also dooming his daughters' marital attempts.

(It's for this reason that [along with receiving their father's plot, they also got shidduchim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.36.6-12?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0))

Comment: Odin was also a pretty terrible father, I believe.

Comment: @BabySeal Yeah, but his being king of the gods outweighed his being a terrible father in terms of yichus for his children's shidduchim.